# export a property in a nodejs module

Tags: node.js, properties, module

in nodejs i can export functions like so :-

```
modules.exports = function() {
    return {
        func1 : function() {
            ...
            ...
        },
        func1 : function() {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to export a non function so I can use it like so?

```
var foo = require('bar');
var x = foo.func1();
var y = foo.property1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add it to your returned object:

```
modules.exports = function() {
    return {
        func1 : function() {
            ...
            ...
        },
        func1 : function() {
            ...
            ...
        },
        property1: 'Some value'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your file to import put the following line :

```
module.export.var = "value";
```

and in your code

```
var foo = require('bar');
console.log(foo.var);
```